# Warning of Exception in windowManager.getDefaultDisplay() method

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, screen-size, android-windowmanager

I am using this method below to get the actual width and height in pixels of the device screen inside `onCreate()` method of my `Activity`:

```
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
Point point = new Point();
display.getSize(point);

int absolute_screen_width_in_pixels = point.x;
int absolute_screen_height_in_pixels = point.y;
```

Yet, I have this warning highlighting the possibility of a `NullPointerException`:
[image]

I've never caught this `Exception` yet, and I can't think of a situation where it could happen. What should I do to ensure that this `NullPointerException` is never thrown?

Also, what backup code should I write to get the actual physical screen dimensions in case this method fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the fact that `getSystemService(...)` is internally annotated with `@Nullable`.

In case you passed an invalid system service name (insted of `WINDOW_SERVICE` which is a constant in the `Context` class i believe pass "dummyName") it will return null.

Since you're using a reference that is annotated as "might be null" (windowManager) to get some property (getDefaultDisplay()) hence the IDE warning.

**Conclusion**

It should be safe as long as you are using the pre-defined constants by Android.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I checked in a couple other places, it appears to be the correct approach.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to get WindowManager from getSystemService of context(maybe return null), extract it from an activity.

```
WindowManager windowManager = activity.getWindowManager(); //This method always return not null.

DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int screeWith = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
int screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
```

Hope this help!